# Optimize queries to track trading algorithm performance

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a panel where a user can upload Python trading algorithms acting on the Binance API and track the performance of each algorithm in e.g a chart like this:
[image: Chart with datapoints]

For each algorithm the amount of BTC, USDT and the total funds (USDT + BTC * actual_btc_price) are displayed.

To achieve this I have the following tables.

**algorithms** - Holding all the algorithms and their configuration.

```
                                 Table "public.algorithms"
      Column      |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |         Default
------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
 id               | character varying(255) |           | not null |
 description      | character varying(512) |           | not null |
 start_funds_usdt | numeric                |           | not null | 0.00
 interval         | character varying(3)   |           | not null | '1s'::character varying
 run_every_sec    | integer                |           | not null | 0
 user_id          | integer                |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "algorithms_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "_timescaledb_internal._hyper_4_1_chunk" CONSTRAINT "1_1_history_algorithm_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (algorithm_id) REFERENCES algorithms(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "history" CONSTRAINT "history_algorithm_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (algorithm_id) REFERENCES algorithms(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**history** - Each order buy/sell is stored in history.

```
                                   Table "public.history"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
 algorithm_id | character varying(255)      |           | not null |
 order_id     | character varying(12)       |           |          | NULL::character varying
 action       | character varying(5)        |           |          | NULL::character varying
 btc          | numeric                     |           | not null |
 usdt         | numeric                     |           | not null |
 btc_price    | numeric                     |           | not null |
 created_at   | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
Indexes:
    "history_created_at_idx" btree (created_at DESC)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "history_algorithm_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (algorithm_id) REFERENCES algorithms(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON history FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_functions.insert_blocker()
Number of child tables: 1 (Use \d+ to list them.)
```

In the chart I want to display the value of btc, usdt, and total funds for every minute. Note that there were the following impediments:

- Not every minute a order is executed and thus the table history doesn't have a record for each minute.
- The price of BTC is volatile so the value of total_funds can vary even if the algorithm is not running or isn't making any orders.

The first impedement I have solved by executing the following query every minute using cronjob in my Rust code:

```
# {} is the current btc_price retrieved by the Binance API.
DO
$$
    declare f record;
         begin
              for f in SELECT DISTINCT id from algorithms
                    loop
                        insert into history(algorithm_id, btc, usdt, btc_price) values (f.id, 0.0, 0.00, {});
                    end loop;
end
$$;
```

By executing this I have access to the latest btc_price for every minute in the table `history` even if a order was not made on that minute.

The following issue was that my initial approach was slow: I took the first timestamp available in history for a given algorithm, add a minute to that one until the current time is reached, and in that loop summed all the values of the columns USDT and BTC where the `created_at` value was lower then the timestamp in the loop.

This was incredibly slow. I solved it by making a view called **history_aggregate**.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW history_aggregate AS
SELECT
    created_at,
    algorithm_id,
    SUM(usdt) OVER (PARTITION BY algorithm_id ORDER BY created_at) AS total_usdt,
    SUM(btc) OVER (PARTITION BY algorithm_id ORDER BY created_at) as total_btc
FROM
    history
GROUP BY
    algorithm_id, history.btc, history.btc_price, history.usdt, history.created_at;
```

This view gets refreshed every minute. This way the calculations (summing for each minute) is already done in the background before it's requested.

When the chart is requested the following query gets executed:

```
    WITH btc_price_cte AS (
SELECT btc_price FROM history where algorithm_id = $1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    )
SELECT
             start_funds_usdt + COALESCE(h.total_usdt, 0) + COALESCE(h.total_btc * btc_price_cte.btc_price, 0) AS current_funds_total,
             start_funds_usdt + COALESCE(h.total_usdt, 0) AS current_funds_usdt,
            COALESCE(h.total_btc, 0) AS current_funds_btc,
            h.created_at::TEXT AS ts
        FROM
            algorithms
        LEFT JOIN
            history_aggregate h ON h.algorithm_id = algorithms.id
        CROSS JOIN
            btc_price_cte
        WHERE
            algorithms.id = $1
        GROUP BY
            algorithm_id, start_funds_usdt, h.total_usdt, h.total_btc, btc_price_cte.btc_price, h.created_at
        ORDER BY h.created_at;
```

I use a Common Table Expression to retrieve the price of BTC at a given timestamp, and by calling data from the view I can get the USDT and BTC amount the algorithm had on that specific timestamp.

This approach works and seems to even run pretty fast. But I was wondering if this approach could be optimized by for example using TimescaleDB?

Comment: Skimming over this I see a couple of angles to optimize, but I think this is paid work for a consultant, rather than a *question* here on dba.SE.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am not asking for a full worked out improvement. It is for a learning project so I'd like to do it myself. Could you just give me some pointers, keywords or references in the right direction? And second question: Is this implementation okay on it's own even without improvements?